# ffmpeg segmentation fails with floating point exception

Tags: video, ffmpeg, segment, floating-point-exceptions, gopro

I'm trying to segment a video using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i /home/user/videos/0001.MP4 -codec copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_frames 66 /tmp/boos/0001/0001_%03d.MP4
```

After working for a few seconds, the output being

```
frame=  251 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=00:00:10.02 bitrate=N/A speed=19.6x
```

the process fails with a floating point exception. The full output is given below. I have a suspicion that the problem may be specific to GoPro videos due to the following observations:

1. The same video is segmented successfully if I first re-encode it using ffmpeg.
2. Other videos (non-GoPro) do not cause the problem.

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to track down or even solve the problem.

**Full output:**

```
ffmpeg version 3.4.8-0ubuntu0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.2 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from &apos;/home/broadbelt/videos/0001.MP4&apos;:
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp41
    minor_version   : 538120216
    compatible_brands: mp41
    creation_time   : 2019-11-18T13:55:42.000000Z
    firmware        : HD7.01.01.80.00
  Duration: 00:17:38.22, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 30245 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 30000 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-11-18T13:55:42.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro AVC  
      encoder         : GoPro AVC encoder
      timecode        : 13:55:42:21
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 189 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-11-18T13:55:42.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro AAC  
      timecode        : 13:55:42:21
    Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74) (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-11-18T13:55:42.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro TCD  
      timecode        : 13:55:42:21
    Stream #0:3(eng): Data: none (gpmd / 0x646D7067), 37 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-11-18T13:55:42.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro MET  
    Stream #0:4(eng): Data: none (fdsc / 0x63736466), 9 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-11-18T13:55:42.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro SOS  
<span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#FF87FF">[segment @ 0x562a95062f40] </font></span>Opening &apos;/tmp/boost/0001/0001_000.MP4&apos; for writing
<span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#FF87FF">[mp4 @ 0x562a9506a600] </font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#FF0000">Timecode frame rate must be specified</font></span>
Output #0, segment, to &apos;/tmp/boost/0001/0001_%03d.MP4&apos;:
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp41
    minor_version   : 538120216
    compatible_brands: mp41
    firmware        : HD7.01.01.80.00
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 30000 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-11-18T13:55:42.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro AVC  
      encoder         : GoPro AVC encoder
      timecode        : 13:55:42:21
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 189 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-11-18T13:55:42.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro AAC  
      timecode        : 13:55:42:21
    Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74) (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-11-18T13:55:42.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro TCD  
      timecode        : 13:55:42:21
    Stream #0:3(eng): Data: none (gpmd / 0x646D7067), 37 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-11-18T13:55:42.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro MET  
    Stream #0:4(eng): Data: none (fdsc / 0x63736466), 9 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-11-18T13:55:42.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro SOS  
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -&gt; #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -&gt; #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #0:2 -&gt; #0:2 (copy)
  Stream #0:3 -&gt; #0:3 (copy)
  Stream #0:4 -&gt; #0:4 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
**Floating point exception (core dumped)me=00:00:01.00 bitrate=N/A speed=0.143x**
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in older versions of ffmpeg, triggered in a few cases by copying the timecode track to MP4/MOV output segments. I patched it last June. So upgrade to 4.3 or a recent git build.